# Combine 2 queries into 1 table with user entering the parameters twice for both queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, datatable

My project needs me to come up with a query which can compare any 2 months data side by side, by just keying in the dates of the 2 months.

I have done 2 separate queries that can only do single month data because I can only enter 1 date per query. I tried to combine this 2 separate query into 1 single query by selecting the columns from each table but it gives me blank data.

I will need some help in combining the 2 queries together, into 1 table as a view form and allowing the user to key in the 2 dates they want to get their data from. Below will be the 2 queries result I can achieve and also the end result I want to achieve from combining this 2 queries.

Conditions to merge the two table is that the company will be the same for both dates, and the item the company bought (if any). If the company did not buy the item on the month , data should be blank.

**Query 1 : User will enter "First month" they want the data from**

```
Inv Number     Company       Date     Item    Price  Quantity  Total    
  123            ABC       1/1/2018   Table     5       3        15
  123            ABC       1/1/2018   Chair     2       4        8
  345            XYZ       1/1/2018   Table     5       5        25
  345            XYZ       1/1/2018   Chair     2       6        12
```

**Query 2: User will enter "Second Month" they want the data from**

```
   Inv Number      Company       Date     Item   Price  Quantity  Total    
      999            ABC       1/2/2018   Table    4       3        12
      999            ABC       1/2/2018   Chair    2       5        10
      899            XYZ       1/2/2018   Table    4       3        12
```

**End result : User will be allowed to key in both dates they want the data from**

```
    Inv Number      Company      Date     Item    Price  Quantity  Total        Date      Item     Price  Quantity  Total    Inv Number
      123            ABC       1/1/2018   Table     5       3        15       1/2/2018    Table      4       3        12        999
      123            ABC       1/1/2018   Chair     2       4        8        1/2/2018    Chair      2       5        10        999
      345            XYZ       1/1/2018   Table     5       5        25       1/2/2018    Table      4       3        12        899
      345            XYZ       1/1/2018   Chair     2       6        12
```

Comment: You probably should show us your queries.

Comment: Join the two queries to a dataset of all possible company/item pairs using compound join. Or build a report and use side-by-side subreports.